# Expo Router v3 Tabs not shown, missing something?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I've tried all sorts of modifications, but I'm not able to make tabs navigation work. For some reason the tabs do not show.

I have a note app, index is just a mural with all the notes, when clicked, they should go to a tabs with an edit screen and a view screen.

[image: This is my folder structure]

This is app/__layout.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { Slot } from "expo-router";
import {
  SafeAreaProvider,
  initialWindowMetrics,
} from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import useStore from "../hooks/useStore";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function RootLayout() {

  const loadNotes = useStore(state => state.loadNotes);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadNotes();
  }, [loadNotes]);

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
        <View style={styles.mainView}>
          <StatusBar style="light" />
          <Slot />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    flex: 1,
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(51,52,53)",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

This is (tabs)/__layout.js:

```
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";

export default function TabsLayout() {

  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();
  
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="edit/[id]"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "edit",
          title: "edit",
          href: {
            pathname: "/edit/[id]",
            params: {
              id: id,
            },
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="view/[id]"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "view",
          title: "view",
          href: {
            pathname: "/view/[id]",
            params: {
              id: id,
            },
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

And in tabs/index.js I simply do a redirect:

```
import { Redirect, useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";

export default function TabsLayout() {
  
  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();

    return (<Redirect href={`/edit/${id}`}/>)

}
```

Reproducible example: Just clone and run the app https://github.com/danielx-art/notes

I've tried changing paths, alterind screenOptions on tabs, removing SafeAreaContext and GestureHandler..., removing index file from (tabs), creating index files for both (tabs)/edit and (tabs)/view all with no success, I feel I'm missing something here.